# Makefile does not iterate over all the source files?

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I want to compile many source file and build a library from them.

My makefile looks approximately like this:

```
SOURCES :=  /home/test/src/\*.c
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

.PHONY: compileLibrary
compileLibrary:
$(CC) -fPIC -c $(SOURCES) -o $(OBJECTS)
$(CC) -shared -o libshared.so $(OBJECTS)
```

How ever the process does not iterate over each source file, it seems that makefile does not replace the * in `SOURCES` by its value.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the source files since you last ran make?

Comment: No. I will echo the value of SOURCES to make sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `*.c`, on its own, is not expanded, you have to use the `wildcard` function (like `$(wildcard *.c)`)
2. It is `*.c`, not `\*.c`. `\` is escape and *removes* the special meaning of `*`.
3. Obviously your makefile shouldn't contain absolute path. Normally the current directory has to be the one where the makefile is in, so take advantage of it.
4. You should be actually using the features of make:

   ```
   libshared.so: $(OBJECTS)
           $(CC) -shared -o $@ $<
   compileLibrary: libshared.so
   ```

   (note: you can probably do without the compilation rule, because the default is likely good enough)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did the backslash because of stackoverflow (it interpret the * so I had to put \ in front of it)

Comment: @Bionix1441, in a verbatim block (indented by 4 spaces, or in backquotes), it does not interpret `*`.

Comment: so I make two rules, one for creating the object files and one for linking them, which is the one you have mentioned here

Comment: @Bionix1441, the default `%.o: %.c` rule is likely good enough, so it's enough to define the link rule with `$(OBJECTS)` as dependencies.